# Fetch author data based on book author_id

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have two database tables:

```
books: id | title | author_id
authors: id | name
```

typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Author {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
  }

  type Book {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    author_id: String!
    author: Author!
  }

  type Query {
    book(id: ID!): Book
    author(id: ID!): Author
  }
`
```

Resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async book(parent, args) {
      const dbRes = await query('SELECT id, title, author_id FROM books WHERE id=$1', [args.id])

      return dbRes[0]
    },
    async author(parent, args) {
      const dbRes = await query('SELECT id, name FROM authors WHERE id=$1', [args.id])

      return dbRes[0]
    }
  }
}
```

I can make request to get book:

```
const queryBook = gql`
  query Book($id: ID!) {
    book(id: $id) {
      id
      title
      author_id
    }
  }
`
const { data } = useQuery(queryBook, { variables: { id: 1 } })
```

But how can i make request for book with author data based on author_id like this?

```
const queryBook = gql`
  query Book($id: ID!) {
    book(id: $id) {
      id
      title
      author_id
      author {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a custom resolver for the author of a Book

```
  const resolvers = {
       Book: {
          author: (parent) => {
                   console.log(parent.author_id)
            return (from database or any where....);
          },
        },

      .
      .
      .
    }
```

Comment: Could be helpful https://www.robinwieruch.de/graphql-apollo-server-tutorial

Comment: You have it for Author .not Book->author.

Comment: yes but resolver code is the same, only id in first case came from arg and in second from parent

Comment: Author type(author) and Query type(author) are different, even the resolver code receive input parameter from a different source, I will try to find a good explanation article for you.